# Python How to copy value from an Entry field to a Text field in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I’m trying to make a simple GUI with Tkinker that when you press a button it adds the value in the Entry field to the next row in the Text field.

```
from tkinter import *

#def onclick():
#   pass

class MyApp:
    def __init__(self):
        window=Tk()
        window.title('Multi Line Text Form')
        frame = Frame(window)
        frame.pack()
        #self.fields ={}

        l = Label(frame, text="Text to add below: ")
        l.grid(row=0, column = 0)
        #self.fields['name'] = Entry(frame)
        name = Entry(frame)
        #self.fields['name'].grid(row=0,column=1)
        name.grid(row=0,column=1)

        self.text = Text(frame, width=40, height=10)
        self.text.grid(row=3,column=1)
        self.text.insert(INSERT, "Hello.....")
        self.text.insert(END, "Bye Bye.....")

        msg = name.get()

        updatebtn = Button(frame, text="Update Text Box", command=self.writeToLog(name))
        updatebtn.grid(row=0, column=2)

        window.mainloop()


    def writeToLog(self, msg):
        print(msg)
        numlines = self.text.index('end - 1 line').split('.')[0]
        #text['state'] = 'normal'
        if numlines==4:
            self.text.delete(1.0, 2.0)
        if self.text.index('end-1c')!='1.0':
            self.text.insert('end', '\n')
        self.text.insert('end', msg)
        #text['state'] = 'disabled'


if __name__=="__main__":
    MyApp()
```

Comment: So... what is your question?

Comment: Have you read the documentation on the Text and Entry widgets? Do you know how to get data out of the widgets? Do you know how to put data into the widgets? What part of the problem do you need help with?

Comment: After entering a value into the Entry field and clicking the button it don't show-up in the text field. I'm not clear how to pass the value to the writeToLog method. Nothing happens when I click the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button needs to be configured with the *name* of a function to call. This function can then get the value from the entry widget and put it in the text widget:

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
   updatebtn = Button(command=self.update_text)
   ...
   self.name_entry = Entry(frame)

def update_text(self):
    data = self.name_entry.get()
    self.writeToLog(data)
```